# Indenting a tree file structure from string input

Tags: java, indentation, subdirectory, file-structure, tree-structure

[Click here to see a screenshot of the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZM46.png)

[Here is how the Navigation.csv looks like, where I take data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K51CG.png)

https://pastebin.com/JXnaRTzi `<-- Click on the link for code` - this is my code so far, I am reading the file and making objects from each entry

Guys I need help with this assignment. I chose to do it in Java, but really it doesn't matter. I need advise and help for making the right approach on this kind of problem so it can work on a larger file. What kind of data structures should I use and maybe if it's no bother, give me a solution. I am a new developer and I'm trying to get into backend and frankly I'm a bit lost.

Click on links above to see the task details.

Comment: use the data structure which you mention in the title... try and fail and keep going, otherwise you will not get into backend

Comment: Think about it yourself and try different approaches. Thats the best way to learn it. I suppose you got stuck where you are right now. If you add a private List<NodeInfo> children to your NodeInfo you can continue. Have fun :-)